# How do I read documents in Risen 1?

Tags: risen

I'm playing the Windows GOG release of Risen with keyboard, mouse and controller. I have received [a list from Master Belschwur](http://mikesrpgcenter.com/risen/items/documents.html#list_from_master_belschwur) with names of people I should be healing. But I can't open the list to read the names. In the meantime, I can get the list from [various](http://risen.wikia.com/wiki/Medicine_for_everyone) [walkthroughs](http://www.gamershell.com/faqs/risenfaqwalkthrough/0.23/), but there will be more quest documents in the future. How do I read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [open your inventory with the "I" button](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/952152-risen/51662240), not via the character stats menu ("C" button). You can then select your list and read it.